# Sobolev spaces and using monotone convergence theorem (don't understand a paper)

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, convergence-divergence, sobolev-spaces, bochner-spaces

I'm reading [this paper](http://www.gillesfrancfort.com/Site/Publications_files/published.version.BF91%20copy.pdf). In it there the following argument (see page 240).

[image]

Firstly, what precisely does the author mean by the displayed equation after 66? The PDE in (65) only holds weakly.. $\frac{\partial b(\overline{v}_n)}{\partial t}$ is only in $H^1(0,T;H^{-1})\cap L^\infty(0,T;L^s)$. He just integrates it in time.. I don't follow.

Secondly, I am lost with the spaces when he says that $\int_0^T \overline{v}_n(s)\;ds$ is a Cauchy sequence in the space $L^\infty(0,T;W^{1,r}_0)$. And then he uses the monotone convergence theorem to say that $\overline{v}_n$ convreges strongly in $L^1(\Omega \times (0,T))$ to some $\overline{v}$. Again a different space. Any explanation appreciated.

Comment: Have you cross posted it on math overflow ?

Comment: @Julien__ Yes actually, here is the link: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/173519/a-question-about-pde-argument-involving-monotone-convergence-theorem-and-sobolev?noredirect=1#comment437491_173519